# React useCallback is only working once between 2 child components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

```
function Route()
{
    const [Items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [status, setQuotestatus] = useState(true);
    const [quotation, setQuotation] = useState({quoteNo: "", type: "Project", quoteDate: "", validity: "", total: 0});
const callback = useCallback((Items,quotation) =>
    {
        setItems(Items);
        setQuotation(quotation);
        console.log(status)
        setQuotestatus(!status);
        console.log(quotation,status);
    }, [],);
 if(status)
    {
        return (<Quote allItems={Items} quote={quotation} parentCallback={callback} />);
    }
    else
    {
        return (<Documents Items={Items} quote={quotation} parentCallback={callback} />);
    }
}

export default Route;
```

I'm using useCallBack to switch and pass parameters between 2 child components that have same parent component `<Route />`. The default case and first switching is working on using use Callback, but when I tried to call this same useCallback from the next components it is calling the hook but component is not shifting to next.
That is I'm able to go to `<Quote />`, then able move to `<Documents />`. But unable to move back to `<Quote />` from `<Documents />`

Button on `<Quote />`

```
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); parentCallback(storedItems, {quoteNo: quoteNo, type: type, quoteDate: quoteDate, validity: validity, total: total})}} >
Preview
</button>
```

Button on `<Documents />`

```
<div className="col">
     <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); parentCallback(storedItems, {quoteNo: quote.quoteNo, type: quote.type, quoteDate: quote.quoteDate, validity: quote.validity, total: quote.total})}} >Back</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `status` in `useCallback` but you don't pass it into dependencies. So status always is initial value.

You should using setState callback in this case:

```
const callback = useCallback((Items,quotation) =>
    {
        setItems(Items);
        setQuotation(quotation);
        setQuotestatus(preStatus => !preStatus );
    }, [],);
```

And you should put `console.log` into `useEffect` because the state only has new value when component re-render

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(quotation,status);
}, [quotation, status])
```

Comment: What is preStatus?

Comment: it is function update: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling setState inside callback use a external function to change state

```
    const [Items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [status, setQuotestatus] = useState(true);
    const [quotation, setQuotation] = useState({quoteNo: "", type: "Project", quoteDate: "", validity: "", total: 0});

    function preState(){
        setQuotestatus(!status);
    }

    const callback = useCallback((Items,quotation) =>
    {
        setItems(Items);
        setQuotation(quotation);
        preState();
    }, [Items, quotation],);
```